# What china users see for reCaptcha

Tags: proxy, recaptcha, firewall

I want to know what do china users see when they enter into a page that have google's reCaptcha. Is it just a blank screen or reCaptcha with red text.
In other words is: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js accessible from china or not.
If this is not the right place to ask this question, then please redirect me to the right place.
Thanks

Comment: Why would you think this would be a good place to ask this information? I would think that asking on [Googles ReCAPTCHA Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/recaptcha) or Google's Chinese Language Group would be a better place to start.

Comment: @Martin the way you replied is soo not nice. I asked for the good place, you could've simply answered by what is the good place. try to be nice next time

Comment: I don't think I was rude, and I'm sorry if you felt that I was, however SO has thousands of questions every day and your question falls a long way short of being a worthwhile and valuable question to the community, either on topic (it's not) or on content. For content, please read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for a guide. I did also suggest you some places where you can dig out your own answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think the availability it's not granted. Can work sometimes but it's better to use recaptcha alternatives.

Answer (score -4):

https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js is accessible from any country

Comment: Even china?, then what is blocked in china while using reCaptcha? thank you by the way

Comment: No, is not accessible in china https://www.greatfirewallofchina.org/index.php?siteurl=www.google.com